# Find a certain value in files on OS X

Tags: macos, search

On every OS I have ever been on I have found a way to find in files.  That is obtain a list of files that have a certain values in them.

So it would seem that the Finder is the place to start.  Not seeing an obvious option to "find in files", I checked help.  In fact I searched help for "find in files".  Nothing appears.

Does anyone know where the Finder option is for doing this?  Or is this a really unusual thing to want to find files based on content rather than a file name.

I realize that I could open a shell window and try to recall the `find` and `grep` combination that solves all, however I prefer to do it through the GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click the loupe at the top right (either in the menu bar or any Finder window). It's your access to [Spotlight](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2531), the search utility in OS X.

[image]

In the results (click *Show all*), you can select *Contents* instead of *File name*.

[image]

To further narrow down your search, click the small <kbd>+</kbd> icon on the right. You could then select the kind of files, restrict your results to a certain size, etc.